# How can I get a list of pages that allow all users from web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How get web config location element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156534/how-get-web-config-location-element)

My web.config has a few pages that we alllow unauthenticated users to view. Is there a way to loop through this list at runtime?

```
  <location path="default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="default2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

**EDIT**

I want a list of all unauthorized pages so that I can exlude them from some javascript code that pops up a reminder when their session is about to time out.

http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-mint.htm

Answer (score 1):

Look into [SiteMaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx), which can be trimmed by authorization and iterated via loops like `SiteMap.CurrentNode.ChildNodes`.  You would also need to maintain a `SiteMap.xml` with a complete sitemap matching your page structure for this to work.

If, for example, your goal is generate a site navigation menu specifically for non-authorized users, then there are built-in controls like `SiteMapDataSource` which when combined with `Menu` control can generate menus tailored to the user's current role authorization automatically, for authorized and non-authorized users alike.

Comment: I want to get a list of all unauthorized pages so that I can exclude them from some javascript code that pops up 60 seconds before their session times out.

Comment: I added an example of what the javascript is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: [System.Configuration.ConfigurationLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationlocation.aspx)

There is sample code that shows getting the ConfigurationLocationCollection. You should then be able to iterate over that collection, get the Path property and do what you are looking to do.

**EDIT**: I was able to properly read the web.config using this code:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap =
new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = Server.MapPath("/web.config");
Configuration config =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationLocationCollection myLocationCollection = config.Locations;
foreach (ConfigurationLocation myLocation in myLocationCollection) {
    Response.Write(String.Format("Location Path: {0}", myLocation.Path));
    Configuration myLocationConfiguration = myLocation.OpenConfiguration();
    Response.Write(String.Format("Location Configuration File Path: {0}",
        myLocationConfiguration.FilePath));
}
```

However, just as you mentioned in the comments, the ConfigurationLocationCollection is empty! I have 6 location entries in my web.config, so this is definitely strange.

Comment: I tried their code, and I was able to load the web.config file into a `config` variable, but the locations value is empty.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it to. The debugger shows it looks for `web.config.config` which is why the collection is empty. Odd... And if you don't pass in the specific name `web.config` it barfs. It has something to do with the ConfigurationManager method. It must not like OpenExeConfiguration for a web app.

Comment: Okay, I did some more searching. There is the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156534/how-get-web-config-location-element). An answer the same as mine has up votes, but we've shown it won't work properly. Check out the accepted answer. It may help you.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is more trouble than it's worth.